# wagtail admin super slow page loads

Tags: python-requests, wagtail, django-3.0

I have an existing django 3.0 project that I've integrated Wagtail 2.10.2 into. Wagtail seems to be working ok but the wagtail admin is super slow. The user facing pages themselves are fine.

Django debug toolbar shows that the delay is due to the browser request taking 5 - 8 seconds for each page load. The time panel shows 74601 involuntary context switches (5 voluntary.)

This is happening on a localserver. I have only a handful of wagtail page objects and the database size is small.

I've run `collectstatic` and all the GET requests are either `200` or `304`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does DDT give you any more useful information about what's taking time? Are you running your server in a VM (e.g. Vagrant) or Docker? Is the database also local? What OS are you using? Is it still slow if you disable DDT?

Comment: oh wow. disabling DDT removes the problem. Thanks for the suggestion!
server isn't running a vm, im using MacOS. Any ideas why DDT caused this?

Comment: I don't know why, I'm afraid, but I've experienced it myself :) Some possible reasons:

https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/search?q=slow&type=issues

Silk is a good alternative:

https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk

Answer (score 4):

Following tomd's suggestion, I disabled django debug toolbar and the problem is resolved. See the links in his comments.